# How authorize a web API using a cookie based authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-webapi, http-token-authentication

I had a MCV core app that uses cookie based authentication (stores user credentials in DB). Later I introduced a web api as the backend of this MVC application. Now both are hosted together as a Azure web app. For now my cookie authentication logic is still in the MVC application. So what is the simplest approach for me to secure the web api.

Comment: how do you authenticate your users ? azure ad ?

Comment: no just uses legacy approach. Store username and password in DB.

Comment: What do you mean by `both are hosted in Azure as a single web` ? Same app service plan ?

Comment: yes in same resource plan but what I meant was both apps are running as a single web app.  Frontend and backend hosted together in the same app.

Comment: SO you have a SPA and a backend ?

Comment: yes @Thomas any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

I simply used the Authorize attribute in my API controllers and that resolved the issue.